# Create a dictionary from two lists having duplicate elements

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Create a dictionary from two lists having duplicate elements where list 1 is the key of the new dictionary and for all strings in list 2 that exactly match list 1, append it to its values field for the keys in list 1. So, for example:

> {'assembla':['assemblabase', 'assemblauploading']}

Like this, I want for each element in list 1

Stuck in this logic:

```
new_d = {}
for j in list2:
    if j == list1 :
        new_d['j'].get('j') 
        print(new_d)
```

**List 1:**

```
list1 = ['assembla', 'bitbucket', 'cloudapp', 'cloudforge', 'cloudinary', 'concur', 'confluence', 'convo', 'dochub', 'docstoc', 'docusign', 'draw.io', 'dropbox', 'egnyte', 'evernote', 'facebook', 'flickr', 'github', 'gitlab', 'glassdoor', 'globalmeet', 'gotowebinar', 'hightail', 'hootsuite', 'huddle', 'icloud', 'imgur', 'instagram', 'issuu', 'jumpshare', 'linkedin', 'lucidpress', 'mail.ru', 'maytech', 'meetup', 'mega', 'mendeley', 'mixi', 'myspace', 'ning', 'onehub', 'owncloud', 'pastebin', 'pinterest', 'prezi', 'proofhub', 'quip', 'quora', 'readytalk', 'reddit', 'renren', 'screencast', 'scribd', 'sendthisfile', 'sharevault', 'slack', 'slideshare', 'smartsheet', 'soundcloud', 'sourceforge', 'stocktwits', 'storify', 'surveymonkey', 'syncplicity', 'tableau', 'teamdrive', 'teamviewer', 'trello', 'tumblr', 'twitter', 'viber', 'vimeo', 'vine', 'virustotal', 'workday', 'yammer', 'youtube', 'zendesk', 'zenefits']
```

**List 2:**

```
list2 = ['2ch', '2chbase', '2chposting', '51.com', '51.commail', '51.combase', '51.combbs', '51.composting', '51.comwebdisk', '51.commusic', '51.comgames', 'adobeconnect', 'adobemeeting', 'adobemeetingdesktopsharing', 'adobemeetinguploading', 'adobemeetingfiletransfer', 'adobemeetingremotecontrol', 'adobeconnectnow', 'adobeconnectnowbase', 'adobeconnectnowfiletransfer', 'adobeconnectnowremotecontrol', 'adobecreativecloud', 'adobecreativecloudbase', 'adobecreativeclouduploading', 'aim', 'aimbase', 'aimvideo', 'aimaudio', 'aimfiletransfer', 'aimexpress', 'aimexpressbase', 'aimexpressfiletransfer', 'aliwangwang', 'aliwangwangbase', 'aliwangwangaudiovideo', 'aliwangwangfiletransfer', 'aliwangwangremotecontrol', 'amazonclouddrive', 'amazonclouddrivebase', 'amazonclouddriveuploading', 'amazonmusic', 'amazonmusicbase', 'amazonmusicstreaming', 'amebanow', 'amebanowbase', 'amebanowposting', 'assembla', 'assemblabase', 'assemblauploading', 'autodesk360', 'autodesk360base', 'autodesk360uploading', 'avayawebalive', 'avayawebalivebase', 'avayawebalivedesktopsharing', 'avayawebalivevoice', 'avayawebalivefiletransfer', 'bacnet', 'bacnetbase', 'bacnetackalarm', 'bacnetconfirmedcovnotify', 'bacnetconfirmedeventnotify', 'bacnetgetalarmsummary', 'bacnetgetenrollmentsummary', 'bacnetsubscribecov', 'bacnetatomicreadfile', 'bacnetatomicwritefile', 'bacnetaddlistelement', 'bacnetremovelistelement', 'bacnetcreateobject', 'bacnetdeleteobject', 'bacnetreadproperty', 'bacnetreadpropconditional', 'bacnetreadpropmultiple', 'bacnetwriteproperty', 'bacnetwritepropmultiple', 'bacnetdevicecommcontrol', 'bacnetconfirmedprivatexfer', 'bacnetconfirmedtextmessage', 'bacnetreinitializedevice', 'bacnetvtopen', 'bacnetvtclose', 'bacnetvtdata', 'bacnetauthenticate', 'bacnetrequestkey', 'bacnetreadrange', 'bacnetlifesafetyoperation', 'bacnetsubscribecovproperty', 'bacnetgeteventinformation', 'baiduhi', 'baiduhibase', 'baiduhiaudiovideo', 'baiduhifiletransfer', 'baiduhigames', 'bebo', 'bebomail', 'bebobase', 'beboposting', 'bitbucket', 'bitbucketbase', 'bitbucketuploading']
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this solves your problem:

```
new_dict = {}
for i in list1:
    new_dict[i] = []
    for j in list2:
        if i in j:
            new_dict[i].append(j)
```

Comment: I am sorry, the output should be like {'assembla' : ['assemblabase', 'assemblauploading']} so the matching element is not duplicated in the value field

Comment: Adding   if i in j and i!= j : and this works fine now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a combined dict/list comprehension (it is shorter, but has worse readability):

```
new_dict = {key:[val for val in list2 if key in val and not key == val] for key in list1 if key in list2}
```

On my machine I get the following output:

```
{'assembla': ['assemblabase', 'assemblauploading'], 'bitbucket': ['bitbucketbase', 'bitbucketuploading']}
```

Updated with your more precise problem description. Just added a second condition within the list comprehension.

Comment: I am sorry, the output should be like {'assembla' : ['assemblabase', 'assemblauploading']} so the matching element is not duplicated in the value field

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a really big comprehension :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'd recommend to break this down a bit if you work on this with other devs as it is not easily understandable at a first glance. However if this is just something you use, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Use zip to create dict out to two list 

`a=[1,2]
b=["a","b"]
c=zip(a,b)
c=dict(c)`

Comment: Please read the whole post before answering the question it. This does not produce the desired output.